# How can I call individual columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand this must be a very basic question, but oddly enough, the resources I've read online don't seem very clear on how to do the following:

How can I index specific columns in `pandas`?

For example, after importing data from a csv, I have a pandas `Series` object with individual dates, along with a corresponding dollar amount for each date.

Now, I'd like to group the dates by month (and add their respective dollar amounts for that given month). I plan to create an array where the indexing column is the month, and the next column is the sum of dollar amounts for that month. I would then take this array and create another pandas Series object out of it.

My problem is that I can't seem to call the specific columns from the current pandas series object I have.

Any help?

Edited to add:

```
from pandas import Series
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

series = Series.from_csv('FCdata.csv', header=0, parse_dates = [0], index_col =0)

print(series)

pyplot.plot(series)
pyplot.show() # this successfully plots the x-axis (date) with the y-axis (dollar amount)

dates = series[0]  # this is where I try to call the column, but with no luck
```

This is what my data looks like in a csv:

```
Dates   Amount
1/1/2015    112
1/2/2015    65
1/3/2015    63
1/4/2015    125
1/5/2015    135
1/6/2015    56
1/7/2015    55
1/12/2015   84
1/27/2015   69
1/28/2015   133
1/29/2015   52
1/30/2015   91
2/2/2015    144
2/3/2015    114
2/4/2015    59
2/5/2015    95
2/6/2015    72
2/9/2015    73
2/10/2015   119
2/11/2015   133
2/12/2015   128
2/13/2015   141
2/17/2015   105
2/18/2015   107
2/19/2015   81
2/20/2015   52
2/23/2015   135
2/24/2015   65
2/25/2015   58
2/26/2015   144
2/27/2015   102
3/2/2015    95
3/3/2015    98
```

Comment: Im not sure I follow, but to get the amount of dollars for a month in a series, you can do `pd.groupby(s, by=s.index.month).sum()` where `s` is your `Series` object. Also there are no columns in a series. Columns are for dataFrames.

Comment: `pd.read_csv` shouldn't be returning a `Series` object unless there's only 1 column in the data, but you said there's more than 1 col. It should return a `DataFrame` object which allows you to access columns. How are you reading the csv file in?

Comment: Thanks for your responses- I'll update my question with my code momentarily

Comment: Please also post sample data

Comment: Please see updates- thanks!

Comment: Please don't post pictures. They cannot be copy pasted. Post raw data and format it as code.

Comment: @ayhan Done- thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the CSV file into a Series. A Series is a one-dimensional object - there are no columns associated with it. You see the index of that Series (dates) and probably think that's another column but it's not.

You have two alternatives: you can convert it to a DataFrame (either by calling `reset_index()`  or `to_frame`  or use it as a Series.

```
series.resample('M').sum()
Out: 
Dates
2015-01-31    1040
2015-02-28    1927
2015-03-31     193
Freq: M, Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

Since you already have an index formatted as date, grouping by month with resample is very straightforward so I'd suggest keeping it as a Series.

However, you can always convert it to a DataFrame with:

```
df = series.to_frame('Value')
```

Now, you can use `df['Value']`  to select that single column. resampling can be done both on the DataFrame and the Series:

```
df.resample('M').sum()
Out: 
            Value
Dates            
2015-01-31   1040
2015-02-28   1927
2015-03-31    193
```

And you can access the index if you want to use that in plotting:

```
series.index  # df.index would return the same
Out: 
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04',
               '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-12',
               '2015-01-27', '2015-01-28', '2015-01-29', '2015-01-30',
               '2015-02-02', '2015-02-03', '2015-02-04', '2015-02-05',
               '2015-02-06', '2015-02-09', '2015-02-10', '2015-02-11',
               '2015-02-12', '2015-02-13', '2015-02-17', '2015-02-18',
               '2015-02-19', '2015-02-20', '2015-02-23', '2015-02-24',
               '2015-02-25', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-27', '2015-03-02',
               '2015-03-03'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Dates', freq=None)
```

---

Note: For basic time-series charts, you can use pandas' plotting tools.

`df.plot()`  produces:

[image]

And `df.resample('M').sum().plot()`  produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. You clarified my misunderstandings and went the extra mile by providing me with detailed explanations into alternatives.